# "return" statement with "for loop"

Tags: java, return-value, return

In java programming language, How can I implement "for loop" in return statement

I have this code

```
public String toString(){
return String.format(num[0]+" - "+num[1]+" - "+num[2]+" - "+num[3]+" - "+num[4]+" - "+num[5]+" - "+num[6]+" - "+num[7]+" - "+num[8]+" - "+num[9]+" - "+num[10]+" - "+num[11]+" - "+num[12]+"\n");
}
```

if  num array have 1000 items , and I want to return all of these elements, how can I do that with out write it one by one like a previous one..

I tried by using for loop but give me an error

```
public String toString(){
for(int j=0 ; j<100 ; j++)
return String.format(num[j]+" - ");
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what language this is!!

Comment: I'm guessing C# or Java.

Comment: java , sorry I forget to mention that

Answer (score 4):

If you do a `return` inside of a loop, it breaks the loop. What you want to do is to return a big string with all those other strings concat. Do a

```
public String toString(){
for(int j=0 ; j<100 ; j++)
s = s +" "+num[j];
}
```

where s is a cache string. Then, after the loop, do a `return s;` so you have them all.

Comment: I used it but give me error (.class expected) what does it mean ?

Comment: It probably means you attempted to execute your source file (.java) instead of your compiled bytecode (.class).

Comment: Use a StringBuilder and do `sb.append(" ").append(num[j]);` inside the loop.  Then `return sb.toString();` after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

If this is C#, you could use:

```
return String.Join(" - ", num);
```

If this is Java, you could use [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html):

```
return StringUtils.join(num, " - ");
```

Comment: This is a java code , thank you for your explanation but could you please tell me how to initialize  (StringUtils) I didn't use it before this time. and where should I write it: inside the loop?

Comment: You'll have to download Apache Commons jar and include it in your classpath and import the package in the class you're using it.  No need for the for loop anymore, this one line takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just concat the strings together before the `return`. You also don't need `String.format`. Even better - if this is C# or Java, use a string builder.

Answer (score 0):

Section **14.1 Normal and Abrupt Completion of Statements** of the standard says:

> The break (§14.15), continue (§14.16), and return (§14.17) statements
>   cause a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of
>   statements that contain them.

If you want to return several elements at once, then you may use a collection to aggregate the returned values.